# What do you use for curriculum mapping?

Tags: mathematics, syllabus, curriculum, learning-management-system

I need something like MIT project called Crosslinks: http://crosslinks.mit.edu/

But since it doesn't work properly neither out of the box on my laptop nor on their own site, I need somethings like that to cross subjects in curriculum and represent them in format of graph to show relations and the path from beginning to the end through topics to the students.

[image]

[image]

Do you know anything like that in order to visualize both the prerequisites and what needs to be done during the course?

Thank you!